# How to open a form into a panel from third form?

Tags: c#, winforms

It seems I came to a different way of designing structure. My project has 3 main forms (form parent, form menu, and form childs).

The Parent has a left panel to contain the menu form and another panel for containing the child forms.

Working like:

The parent form opens the menu form in the left panel. While the menu is shown on the left panel, clicking the menu should open a child in the main panel. (both panels are in the parent form).

## Opening the menu:

```
public Home()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    panelmenus.Controls.Clear();
    frmmenus menu = new frmmenus();
    menu.TopLevel = false;
    menu.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panelmenus.Controls.Add(menu);
    menu.Show();
}
```

## Clicking the menu to open the other child in the main panel:

```
 private void btnsetting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Forms.frmEmployee employee = new Forms.frmEmployee()
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        TopLevel = false,
    };
    Home main = new Home();
    main.pncontainer.Controls.Add(employee);
    employee.Show();
}
```

Is it possible to do this way or not? Because I came to this way already.

If there is any other way to do this problem, give me please.

I took few hours for this issue.

Much thank you to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible approach.

The [Parent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.parent?view=netframework-4.8) of your instance of `frmmenus` will be a Panel.  From that Panel you can call [FindForm()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.findform?view=netframework-4.8) to get a reference to the main `Home` instance.  Next you can use [Controls.Find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.8) to search for your Panel called "pncontainer".  From there, simply clear the panel and add your desired form instance to it:

```
private void btnsetting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmEmployee employee = new frmEmployee()
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        TopLevel = false,
    };


    Form frm = this.Parent.FindForm();
    Control match = frm.Controls.Find("pncontainer", true).FirstOrDefault();
    if (match != null && match is Panel)
    {
        Panel p = (Panel)match;
        p.Controls.Clear();
        p.Controls.Add(employee);
        employee.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: A better approach would be to use a custom [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events).  Make your menu form raise an event with the Form to show as a parameter.  The home form would receive that event and then display the passed form in its appropriate panel.

Comment: It's working!!!! Big thanks! It's something more than I can say thank you to you @Idle_Mind.

Comment: All you answer is useful. Thank you to all.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one instance of the parent form (i.e., `Home`), you may use [`Application.OpenForms`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms) to find and access that instance. Then, you can use it (instead of creating a new instance) to display the employee form:

```
private void btnsetting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Home main = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Home>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (main != null)
    {
        Forms.frmEmployee employee = new Forms.frmEmployee()
        {
            TopLevel = false,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };
        main.pncontainer.Controls.Add(employee);
        employee.Show();
    }
}
```

Note that you'll need to set the `Modifiers` property of `pncontainer` to either `Public` or `Internal` for this to work.

If you don't want to use `Application.OpenForms` or you may have multiple instances of `Home`, there are a few ways to still access the right instance of `Home`. One way would be using the [`ParentForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform) property like this:

```
private void btnsetting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Home main = this.ParentForm as Home;
    if (main != null)
    {
        Forms.frmEmployee employee = new Forms.frmEmployee()
        {
            TopLevel = false,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };
        main.pncontainer.Controls.Add(employee);
        employee.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It can't fixed friend.  error  :   System.InvalidOperationException: 'Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling Show.'

Comment: @NamhmoobqubqubY My bad! Using `Owner` won't work in this situation due to the `TopLevel` property being set to false. I've edited the answer.